# discerning between from whom and from

Tags: prepositions, clauses

> (1) The man from whom I got the pen.
>
> (2) **The man from I got the pen.**
>
> (3) The man I got the pen from.
>
> (4) The man whom I got the pen from.

Could you please show me if they are correct, if not would you correct me?

Many thanks

Comment: (1) and (3) are correct. (2) makes no sense. (4) should use _who_ in place of _whom_.

Comment: @J.R. - "from whom" is split apart in (4), that does not change "whom" to "who".

Comment: @Kreiri - Grammatically, you're right. Nice catch. Conversationally, though, I think you'd hear it with "who" more than "whom", particularly with the preposition moved to the end. As an aside, I'm guessing we both agree that No. 4, in its current wording, is probably best avoided altogether :^)

Comment: @Kreiri No, but *who* is nonetheless a much better choice.  If you're going to use *whom*, which marks your writing as rather formal in style, you should also [pied-pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied-piping) *from*, as stranding prepositions is relatively informal; the clash between formal *whom* and informal stranding makes example (4) a poor choice as written.

Comment: @snailboat J.R It's probably best not to tell learners something's wrong if they're going to see it cropping up everywhere, though :)

Comment: 4 is incorrect?? I failed to get what you are talking about... Would you please show me your explanations in more readily way?

Comment: Is #4 incorrect? You could tell us what you find [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=who+vs+whom)... @Araucaria - I think it's best to tell learners when some things they'll see all over are appropriate for more formal contexts, and when others aren't.

Answer (score 2):

> (1) The man from whom I got the pen.
>
> (2) **The man from I got the pen.**
>
> (3) The man I got the pen from.
>
> (4) The man who(m) I got the pen from.

Let's start with example (4) because it's the easiest to talk about:

- (4) .... the man<sub>(i)</sub> [whom <sub>(i)</sub>  I got the pen from ___ <sub>(i)</sub> ]

The *man* here is the antecedent for the word *who(m)*.  There is a gap at the end of the clause that represents a missing word after the preposition *from*. All three parts have the same *index*, they all refer to the same person. We could represent the relative clause like this:

- the man [whom I got the pen from <s>him</s>  ].

Here, the object of the preposition is the word *who(m)*, but *whom* is at the beginning of the clause. The proposition *from* has been 'stranded' at the end of the sentence.

If we want to, we can put the *whole preposition phrase* at the beginning of the clause. This is what happens in example (1):

- (1)  ... the man [**from whom** I got the pen ___ ].

If we arrange the sentence like this, the preposition occurs in the normal position before its object *whom*. We can think about the clause like this:

- ... the man [from whom I got the pen <s>from him</s> ].

Notice that we can only move the preposition so that it comes *before* its object. Otherwise it must stay in its normal position. In these relative clauses, *I* is the subject of the clause. Because the relative word *who(m)* is not the subject, we can drop it. We don't need to use a relative word at all:

- (3) ... the man<sub>(i)</sub> [I got the pen from ____<sub>(i)</sub> ].

There is still a gap at the end of the sentence, where the object of *from* is missing. But there is no relative pronoun *whom* in this sentence. Notice that *from* must be at the end of the clause in its normal position. We cannot move it so that it comes before its object. This is because the object of the word *from* is missing! *From* here occurs before the gap where its object would be. We could represent the clause like this:

- (3) ... the man [I got the pen from  <s>him</s>  ].

If we try to move *from* to  a different position, the clause will be ungrammatical:

- (2) *... the man<sub>(i)</sub> [from I got the pen ___<sub>(i)</sub> ] (wrong).

Here the word *from* doesn't appear before its real object - or the gap left from the missing object. If we try to reconstruct the missing parts we have the following representation:

- (2) *... the man [from I got the pen <s>him</s> ] (wrong).

This is definitely not a good clause!

Hope this is helpful.